# Servlet output to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am writing an application in JAVA. Need advice about the menu.

I dont want to duplicate the code for menu creation in every JSP.

I want to create 1 JSP called menu.jsp and create the menu there and do a dynamic include `<jsp:include... >` wherever I need the menu.

This is fine till I have static menu.

Now, how would do do this for a dynamic menu.

I know it is a bad practice to connect to DB directly from JSP.

So what I want to do is this:

- create a servlet
- connect to DB and get the menu items and the display order
- flush the menu created above to a jsp

So, my question is how do I include the above JSP wherever I need menu???

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a templating system. Try out [sitemesh](http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/) for instance.
If you want to really use a java framework that helps you with good practices, i recommend to use [grails](http://www.grails.org)

Comment: +1 for introducing template system. Here is a list of template engines: http://java-source.net/open-source/template-engines

Answer (score 0):

You may include servlet output by tag [<jsp:include>](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/12/syntaxref1214.html). But it's a bad practice. See [jsp tags](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/JSPTags.html) instead

Comment: I dont want to include the servlet output directly. Lets say I have a url like this: /myapp/menu

Comment: Please ignore the comment above.I dont want to include the servlet output directly. 

Lets say I have a url like this: /myapp/menu.

So the flow is like this

servlet creates a dynamic menu from DB
servlet flushes it to a JSP called menu.jsp

So I want to include menu.jsp wherever I need menu.


Lets say i want to include it in display.jsp

so what should the code be?


Please tell me how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. To use the menu, application wide put the generated menu either in session or application[ If and only if menu is same for every user]
2. Lets say menu.jsp has the code for generating the menu, get the session(or application object) and proceed with the requirement
3. Finally call menu.jsp using  or <%@include >

Answer (score 0):

Add the menu items, and a "renderMenu" boolean as request attributes.

Then include the menu.jsp and read those attributes - if `renderMenu` is false, don't output anything. If it is true - proceed with rendering the items (set by the servlet)